# Not able to delete a document by repo--> delete in Spring Boot 2.x with Webflux

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE, webflux & mongodb-reactive, all my operations are working fine POST, GET, PUT but however delete is not working.
Complete source code of demo app can be seen here at github.com [Source code link](https://github.com/kjoshi07/webflux-crud-demo)

here is my document class:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

and here is my handler method for DELETE request.method is successful returning OK(200) response but when I see mongdb, record is not deleted.

```
 public Mono<ServerResponse> deleteAnEmployee(ServerRequest request) {
        String employeeId = request.pathVariable("id");
        return employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
                .flatMap(employee -> {
                    employeeRepository.delete(employee);
                    return ServerResponse.ok().build();
                }).switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
    }
```

Am I missing something here, please suggest.pom, router, repo, etc please see gihub link provided in description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `delete` is not applied because it is not part of the reactive chain - see [this item in the reactor documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.chain). If operations are not chained, nothing will subscribe to that part of your code and it won't be executed.

In this particular case, you must make sure that the OK response is returned once the delete operation has finished:

```
                return employeeRepository.delete(employee)
                           .then(ServerResponse.ok().build());
```

Note: your employee repository is a bit odd, since it is using `UUID` as an id for documents, whereas you seem to be using `String` in all other places. Maybe you should use `String` instead on the repository interface.

Comment: thanks got it, yes in repo I forgot to change, thank you.